# Load a png blank image with .FromStream() in C# Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a function wrote in `C#` which loads images in `monogame`, but it says the file couldn't be found. This is my code:

```
public static GraphicsAdapter adapter = new GraphicsAdapter();
public static GraphicsProfile profile = new GraphicsProfile();
public static PresentationParameters presentation = new PresentationParameters();
public static GraphicsDevice graphics = new GraphicsDevice(adapter,profile,presentation);

public static Texture2D LoadPicture(string Filename)
        {
            FileStream setStream = File.Open(Filename, FileMode.Open);
            Texture2D NewTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(graphics,setStream);
            setStream.Dispose();
            return NewTexture;
        }
```

the code calling this is:

```
public basic2d(string PATH, Vector2 POS, Vector2 DIMS) 
{ 
            pos = POS; dims = DIMS; myModel = load.LoadPicture(PATH); 
}
```

the path is "2d\testimage.png"

the error in the console is:
Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/username/MyProject/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/Content/2d/testimage.png'.

i don't know why it is trying to load from /bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/ though. As i just want to run from MyProject directly. i don't know how to do this though...

please don't get mad i did search elsewhere online but nothing worked.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is `Filename` just the name of the file, or is it also the path where the file is located? possible chances are that you need to use the path towards the filename instead.

Comment: it's just the name, it's the function i call when i want to get a picture. "2d\\testimage.png" this is the path.

```
public basic2d(string PATH, Vector2 POS, Vector2 DIMS)
        {
            pos = POS;
            dims = DIMS;

            myModel = load.LoadPicture(PATH);
        }
    ```
this is the code that runs it

Comment: keep in mind to edit your question to place additional info, as the comments doesn't allow code formatting.

Comment: @Steven sorry i am new, i edited it now. do you know why it is not working?

Comment: I think the path refers it to the place where the project is build into (MyProject/bin/Debug) Have you tried placing the picture in the path it refers to? Eventually when you're releasing the project, it isn't dependend on the Solution and it's files in MyProject anymore, and the .exe file in the Debug folder would be all you need.